# Is it possible to make a pattern a single word for line wrapping purposes?

Tags: vim

**Edit**: I changed the title to more accurately present what I am asking for. The sentence immediately below should read "is it possible to make a pattern, such as '.*' treated as a single word for line wrapping purposes?"

Using vimwiki, is it possible to prevent a link from being word-wrapped?

Currently,

```
Etiam iaculis tempor dui, et mollis ligula accumsan et. Nam mattis cursus lorem sit amet accumsan. [Mauris elementum turpis eget](magna) ultrices molestie. Maecenas sagittis mauris id lacus consectetur, cursus mollis ex pretium. Quisque volutpat tellus ut augue fermentum ultricies eget eu metus. In lacinia sit amet massa ut feugiat.
```

becomes

```
Etiam iaculis tempor dui, et mollis
ligula accumsan et. Nam mattis cursus
lorem sit amet accumsan. [Mauris
elementum turpis eget](magna) ultrices
molestie. Maecenas sagittis mauris id
lacus consectetur, cursus mollis ex
pretium. Quisque volutpat tellus ut
augue fermentum ultricies eget eu metus.
In lacinia sit amet massa ut feugiat.
```

Note the `Mauris elementum turpis eget` link. The link markdown is broken when the text is reformatted.

Setting a longer textwidth won't solve the issue; I prefer the width I already have, and it will still happen. Link breaking will just happen at different points.

Changing the general word wrap settings won't work either ... they are just the way I like them, except in this one case.

Comment: what do you exactly want? You want vim to wrap text, but not all the time? That is not possible with vim (as far as I know). Usually what is done in this case is to NOT wrap the buffer but only the view. see `:h wrap` for that

Comment: You don't want to stop the wrapping, you want to modify the syntax highlight such that links allow for line breaks.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, I want to make the pattern '[.*](.*)' a single word for purposes of line wrapping.

Comment: @Vitor, I don't think it's syntax highlighting as the link has a newline inserted into it.

Comment: What has a problem with the line break? A Markdown processor shouldn't care about a newline inside the `[...]`.

Comment: @chepner, it is vimwiki's handling of the link that is the problem. The link is parsed correctly after being converted to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comment, `text-width` does limit the column count of your file. You can't turn it on and off based on a line. It is exactly like you would write a small piece of paper, there is just no space left.
Of course, vim has different options to control where exactly it breaks the line (see `h formatoptions` and `h fo-table`) , but they aren't context-sensitive. And as soon as your text between `[` and `]` will be longer than 80 chars, you will have the problem again.

So what are the alternatives?

1. Don't use `text-width` but use `wrap`. This will not limit your column count at all. But will display the lines of text over multiple lines of screen space.
2. `set colorcolumn=80` this does not do anything for you, but highlight the column, so you can wrap the text yourself.
3. Write a custom function, that does the wrapping for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this problem the wrong way.

Vimwiki is not parsing markdown link text with multiple lines correctly, but [wontfix at the moment](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki/issues/978).

So, the options described elsewhere in this question are the only choices at the moment.

I answered this myself because I wanted to include an explanation of what was going on and a  pointer to the relevant issue.